# Relation between two arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple weather app. It shows today and next 4 days weather.

I have two arrays: the first one is `WEEK_DAYS`, the second is an array of dom elements to display name of the day.

I want that top dom element always show today's weather. Second must show tomorrow etc.

________app today should display
-SATURDAY   < first dom element
-SUNDAY
-MONDAY
-FRIDAY
-TUESDAY    < last dom element

________app tomorrow should display
-SUNDAY     < first dom element
-MONDAY
-FRIDAY
-TUESDAY
-WEDNESDAY  < last dom element

```js
const WEEK_DAYS = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const daysElements = document.querySelectorAll("span.font-light");  // dom elements
const date = new Date();
const today = WEEK_DAYS[date.getDay()];  // date.getDay() returns a number: 0 for sunday, 1 for monday ... 6 for Saturday
```

I need ideas here on how to achieve that.

```js
[...daysElements].map((d, index) => {
  d.innerText = WEEK_DAYS.find((e) => e === today);  // of course all dom elements printing "Saturday" (today)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Use numbers in calculations, and strings for display:

```js
const WEEK_DAYS = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const daysElements = document.querySelectorAll("span.font-light");  // dom elements
const date = new Date();
const today = date.getDay();  // date.getDay() returns a number: 0 for sunday, 1 for monday ... 6 for Saturday

daysElements.forEach((d, index) => d.innerText = WEEK_DAYS[(today + index) % 7]);
```

```css
span.font-light {display:block}
```

```html
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
```

Also it's ok to use `forEach` here.

Comment: thanks @Kosh! in ```WEEK_DAYS[(today + index) % 7])``` i replaced today with ```date.getDay()``` cause "today" is a string and it worked! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the respective [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) nodes you want to display using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Here in this example I am using a simple unordered list with list items. The get the parent element (e.g. using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)) and append the children to it using [`replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/replaceChildren) and the nodes are displayed.

```js
const weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
const temperaturesInDegreeCelcius = [21, 23, 19, 10, 18, 25, 24];

const list = document.querySelector(".list");
const listItems = weekdays.map((day, i) => createListItem(day, temperaturesInDegreeCelcius[i]));
list.replaceChildren(...listItems);

function createListItem(day, temperature){
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = `${day}: ${temperature} °C`;
  return li;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answers. I thought I'd add mine as an example of a C-like for loop.

```js
let daysOfWeek = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
const date = new Date();
d = date.getDay();
l = daysOfWeek.length;
const daysElements = document.querySelectorAll("span.font-light");

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  daysElements[i].innerText = daysOfWeek[d % l];
  d++;
}
```

```css
span.font-light {display:block}
```

```html
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
<span class="font-light"></span>
```